# Windows XP multicast route unable to be set on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, multicast, static-routes

I have to set a route that I am setting in windows xp by using this command :

```
route -p add 224.224.224.0 mask 240.240.240.0 150.1.2.194 metric 30
```

Under windows 7, this command doesn't work anymore (bad param).

How can I set this route in windows 7 ?

Regards.

Edit : here is what I am doing on XP :

```
Microsoft Windows XP [version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

C:\Documents and Settings\sylvain>ipconfig

Configuration IP de Windows


Carte Ethernet Connexion au réseau local:

        Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion :
        Adresse IP. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.165.10.244
        Masque de sous-réseau . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
        Passerelle par défaut . . . . . . : 192.165.10.2

C:\Documents and Settings\sylvain>route -p add 224.224.224.0 mask 240.240.240.0
192.165.10.244 metric 30

C:\Documents and Settings\sylvain>route print
===========================================================================
Liste d'Interfaces
0x1 ........................... MS TCP Loopback interface
0x2 ...08 00 27 bb 86 10 ...... Carte AMD PCNET Family Ethernet PCI - Miniport d
'ordonnancement de paquets
===========================================================================
===========================================================================
Itinéraires actifs :
Destination réseau    Masque réseau  Adr. passerelle   Adr. interface Métrique
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.165.10.2  192.165.10.244       20
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0        127.0.0.1       127.0.0.1       1
     192.165.10.0    255.255.255.0   192.165.10.244  192.165.10.244       20
   192.165.10.244  255.255.255.255        127.0.0.1       127.0.0.1       20
   192.165.10.255  255.255.255.255   192.165.10.244  192.165.10.244       20
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0   192.165.10.244  192.165.10.244       20
    224.224.224.0    240.240.240.0   192.165.10.244  192.165.10.244       30
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   192.165.10.244  192.165.10.244       1
Passerelle par défaut :      192.165.10.2
===========================================================================
Itinéraires persistants :
  Adresse réseau    Masque réseau  Adresse passerelle Métrique
    224.224.224.0    240.240.240.0   192.165.10.244      30
```

And the same thing on 7 :

```
Microsoft Windows [version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. Tous droits réservés.

C:\Users\pc>ipconfig

Configuration IP de Windows


Carte Ethernet VoIP - 192.168.0.4 :

   Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . :
   Adresse IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . .: 192.165.10.252
   Masque de sous-réseau. . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0

Carte Ethernet LAN 1 - 192.165.10.242 :

   Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . :
   Adresse IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . .: 192.165.10.242
   Masque de sous-réseau. . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Passerelle par défaut. . . . . . . . . : 192.165.10.2


C:\Users\pc>route -p add 224.224.224.0 mask 240.240.240.0 192.165.10.242 metric
30
L'ajout de l'itinéraire a échoué : Paramètre incorrect.
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `-p` flag comes *before* `add`.

eg: `route -p add 224.224.224.0 mask 240.240.240.0 150.1.2.194 metric 30`

source: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/route.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: Sorry, code sample was from memory, the -p flag is not the problem here. It can be removed the command still doesn't works. (question edited)

Comment: Is your gateway (150.1.2.194) correct? Your syntax looks correct, so there must be an IP conflict. See one user's experience: http://superuser.com/questions/200483/why-does-this-route-add-command-fail

Comment: The gateway ip is the one defined for one of the network adapter. I have modified my question to display the problem.

Comment: Have you made any headway with this?

Comment: Not at all, I have updated the question to show what is the problem, but I can't find what is wrong in windows 7 with this command.

Comment: I still believe your syntax to be correct, can you please post a route print of each machine?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the netmask, a netmask by definition is a mask which defines the bits to apply variation so you cannot have variation in the first 3 of the fields.  If you have a mask of 240.x.x.x then the x.x.x must be 0.0.0.

I have actually just used the command:
route ADD 224.0.0.0 MASK 240.0.0.0 192.168.3.1 IF 21 -p